# Terminal video player

Tags: software-recommendation

I am looking for nice terminal based video player for my Ubuntu 12.04 Xmonad desktop.

I would like to make custom scripts for this player is it's possible.

Can You recommend some?

Comment: Please mark an answer correct if it satisfies your question.

Answer (score 3):

I take it that you mean a video player that is controlled from the Terminal, but creates a windows in X11. In that case, you should go with everyones favorite: mplayer.

Install via:

```
sudo apt-get install mplayer
```

or search for `mplayer` in the Ubuntu Software Center

Comment: Somehow I doubt that he will be using the USC if he is looking for a command line video player. :)

Comment: @chad Well yes, but I didn't think including that would hurt. B)